# #line directive and real usages

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, bison, yacc, preprocessor-directive

Many **C** books say very little about the `#line` directive.

Many of them say that this directive is used by yacc of bison tools but don't show any practical example.

Can anyone show me some real usage of this directive or give me a practical
example of bison or yacc usage?

Comment: What about `man yacc` or `man bison`? (Not trying to be snarky, but the documentation is always the place to start first).

Comment: Take a look at your preprocessor's output (for a file with some `#include`) with `gcc -E`, for example (`c99 -E` for POSIX systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any program or script which generates C (or C++) code from something else in some other file should also emit a lot of `#line` directives (to associate generated C lines to location in that other file).

This is mostly useful for diagnostic messages and for the debugger.

As an example, run [GNU bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison) (a generator of parser code) on some `example.y` file, use [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), and look into the generated C code, or develop then build, install [your GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (it could modify source locations; see also the old -obsolete- [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project and perhaps [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)), or look inside [compilers translating to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) like [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/).

BTW, by experience, when you develop a serious C or C++ code generator, you *need* to emit correct `#line` directives, and that is a significant burden in the code generator. It may require a significant amount of work.

In some cases, you may choose to not generate `#line` directives. In 2021, we are making such a choice in the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project.

Comment: Can you make me a concrete example? Also with pseudo-code?

Comment: Your website link for MELT is out of date and now points to an irrelevant company. A currently valid link is http://starynkevitch.net/basile/gcc-melt/ but be warned that that website states the GCC Melt project is inactive since the end of 2017.